# In a 'summarise(data, lhs = rhs)' call: is there no way to transfer to lhs the attributes of rhs?

Tags: r, dplyr, custom-attributes

Following lines highlight the issue. Attributes are transferred in many cases BUT not in the last one, a common 'summarise' use case. Any help greatly appreciated!

```r
suppressWarnings(suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr)))

obj <- c(12, 13, 51)
attributes(obj)<- list(cv = c(3, 4, 2))
print(obj)
#> [1] 12 13 51
#> attr(,"cv")
#> [1] 3 4 2
## 'obj' has an attribute
print(attributes(obj))
#> $cv
#> [1] 3 4 2

tbl <- tibble::tibble(col = obj)
print(tbl$col)
#> [1] 12 13 51
#> attr(,"cv")
#> [1] 3 4 2
## attributes are retained by the col obj was assigned to
print(attributes(tbl$col))
#> $cv
#> [1] 3 4 2

foo <- function(x){
  # to be called within 'summarise()'
  o <- sum(x)
  attributes(o)<- list(cvv = o*2)
  return(o)
}
# produces values with attributes
print(foo(7))
#> [1] 7
#> attr(,"cvv")
#> [1] 14

tbl2 <- tbl %>% 
  summarise(z = foo(col))
# with one single row, attributes are transferred to tbl2
print(attributes(tbl2$z))
#> $cvv
#> [1] 152

tbl2 <- tbl %>% 
  group_by(col) %>% 
  summarise(z = foo(col), .groups = "keep")
# with more rows, attributes are NO longer present in tbl2
print(attributes(tbl2$z))
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You could wrap them in a `list` i.e. `summarise(z = list(foo(col)), .groups = "keep")` and then check the `tbl2$z` which is a `list` `attributes(tbl2$z[[1]])`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, yes Akrun you are right, list wrapping actually preserves attributes!
To complete the answer and get the desired result (a non-list column with attributes), to my understanding, a fairly convoluted process is required (see code).
Is it possible to achieve the same result without interrupting the 'piping' flow?

```r
suppressWarnings(suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr)))
suppressWarnings(suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(purrr)))

obj <- c(12, 13, 51)
attributes(obj)<- list(cv = c(3, 4, 2))
tbl <- tibble::tibble(col = obj)
print(attributes(tbl$col))
#> $cv
#> [1] 3 4 2

foo <- function(x){
  # to be called within 'summarise()'
  o <- sum(x)
  attributes(o)<- list(cvv = o*2)
  return(o)
}

tbl2 <- tbl %>% 
  group_by(col) %>% 
  summarise(z = list(foo(col)), .groups = "keep")
atts <- map_df(tbl2$z, attributes)
tbl2 <- tbl2 %>% 
  mutate(z = unlist(z))
attributes(tbl2$z)<- atts
# now attributes are present in tbl2!!! but the flow is somewhat twisted!
print(attributes(tbl2$z))
#> $cvv
#> [1]  24  26 102
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>